# In SPSS, how do I combine 3 variables (which consist of both letters and numbers) into 1 variable?

Tags: string, combinations, numeric, spss

I'm analyzing the results of a study and I'm trying to make a unique ID for each participant. This unique ID must consist of the information that the participants already gave me.
I have 3 columns named "ID1," "ID2," and "ID3." For example,for participant #1, under ID1, there is the letter 'T'. Under ID2, there is the number '22'. Under ID3, there is the number '3'. Now I need to make a column/variable that now has T223 as a new ID or answer for this participant. I have to combine ID1, ID2, and ID3 in this manner for all participants.
I have tried to make them all string variables and do Compute Variable, but I'm unsure whether this is the correct route to go.
*Note: there will be duplicates under each ID column; for example, two 'T''s under ID1. However, after participant gets their own unique ID, there will not be any duplicates of the unique ID (or the combination of ID1, ID2, ID3.)

After I get this done, I have to do the same thing for another dataset, and then merge both datasets together according to this new unique ID for each participant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you already have three strings you can merge them into one like this:

```
string ID(a10).
compute ID=concat(ID1, ID2, ID3).
```

If ID2 and ID3 are still numbers, you can go this way (assuming max two digits in the IDs, you can change that as needed):

```
compute ID=concat(ID1, string(ID2, N2), string(ID3, N2)).
```

This might leave you with extra spaces if the number of charachters in ID1 varies. This will help:

```
compute ID=concat(rtrim(ID1), string(ID2, N2), string(ID3, N2)).
```